# Problem applying rigid body physics to chain links generated with array modifier

Tags: modifiers, physics

So I want to build a quick chain with 50 links. However, when I create one link, duplicate it 50 times and then apply a modifier. The rigid body physics go super buggy.

It seems that I can only get a working chain by building it one link at a time. Uggh!

Here's a blend file with the links set up. Array modifiers have not been applied nor any physics.

[image]

Edit:

It has something to do with not being able to apply rigid body physics to a selected group of objects. I seperated the links "by loose parts" in edit mode and then the "origin to geometry" for all the separated parts. But then when I select them all and try to apply a rigid body physics to them all at once, it just doesn't work. The physics has to be applied to each link, one at a time. Hopefully there's a faster way?

Comment: Please ask one question at a time and give your question a matching title. There is no reason why you cannot build a chain using an array modifier - you can.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is twofold:

1. After applying the array modifier and separating the generated links by loose parts, and setting the origins of those parts (see op) You have to apply the rigid body settings you want to the origin of the array, then use F3: copy rigid body settings.
2. The rigid body setting Collisions > Shape has to be set to "Mesh" instead of "Convex Hull".

Those are the issues I was running into.

Other helpful tips include:

1. Under the scene properties tab > Rigid Body World > Steps per second, increase from the default setting to prevent chain breakage.
2. Reduce the weight of individual links (i.e., frmo 1kg to .1kg)